# vue3 template ref is not a reference but the actual referenced element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple vue3 (3.2.31) sfc project and I use typescript (4.6.2):

```
<template>
    <div id="test-div" ref="testDiv" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Options, Vue} from 'vue-class-component';

@Options({
  components: {},
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    
    private testDiv = ref();

    mounted():void {
      console.log(this.testDiv);
      console.log(this.testDiv.classList); // TS does not like that, but browser does
      console.log(this.testDiv.value?.classList); // TS likes that, but browser doesnt
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

Afaik and according to many tutorials about template refs, `testDiv` is a reference. But actually its not. It is a HTMLDivElement. console.log prints `<div id="test-div"></div>`.

The problem is, typescript also expects a reference and tells me `Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'Ref '.` But the browser says `DOMTokenList ['test-class', value: 'test-class']`. `this.testDiv.value` is undefined and browser console gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure it's something really simple and I just can't come up with it. I also wonder why the vue docs doesn't explain how to use template refs. They just mention the super basics. Or did I just not see it?

Comment: Template refs are documented [just fine](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html). Your problem is probably related to usage of [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) plugin. It is part of the core repo but it always felt more like an unofficially plugin. It's version for Vue 3 is in beta stage for [several months](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/584), has no activity and class API usage is [actively discouraged](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#relationship-with-class-api) by Vue current docs

Comment: `ref()` is primarily used with composition API inside `setup`. "What am I doing wrong?" - you're using the lib that does some magic under the hood with undetermined and undocumented behaviour, and it was designed to work with Vue 2, as said above

Comment: OMG I never knew that the class api is some sort of deprecated. This are very bad news. Why the hell isn't this info more prominent? Dont tell me it is. Putting something gamebreaking like this at the and of the docs isn't prominent in my world. We dived deep into the docs with 3 devs the last 5 month and no one noticed. How could that happen... But I always wonderd why there are so less info around using class api and most libraries are written with composition api. But I thought its because vue3 is relatively new. That will be a fun meeting tomorrow. And definately an angry boss.

Comment: Thank you both. You two probably saved us some real trouble. I still dont believe this...